# After adding a script to the startup applications, I've started to have boot errors even when I disable the script

Tags: boot, 18.04, scripts, startup

I recently switched my laptop completely to be a Ubuntu system (18.04.5). I added a startup application to run a setup script for an application. Once I added this script to my start up I've consistently had issues with Ubuntu "starting".

I can get to grub but if I attempt to boot into Ubuntu I'm greeted with a black screen with a row of coloured pixels towards the bottom, see the image below. Similarly, if I let it boot as normal I'm met with the same result.

Annoyingly, this isn't consistent and occasionally my laptop will finish booting to Ubuntu. If I disable the startup application then the issues still occur, but as I said these issues only began to happen after adding the application in the first place.

I have been able to finish booting into Ubuntu and reach the log-in screen, though it's purely down to luck. I'm not really sure what could've caused this as all I've down with Ubuntu so far is install programs required for a course (no boot errors), manually run the setup script and start the program (no boot errors), and then add the setup script to the startup apps (boot errors, even when the app is disabled).

If anyone would be able to give some adivce on what they think the issue could be or how I could attempt to diagnose it (again, I can occasionally reach the login screen) that'd be greatly appreciated. I'm currently running some hardware diagnostics to see if it's a hardware issue anyways.

[image: The line of pixels]

Update 17/10/20:
So the problem is no longer occuring, though I can't really determine why. The laptop now consistently boots to Ubuntu after displaying the line of pixels for a few seconds. I was hesitant to update immediately as I didn't want to jump the gun on the issue being resolved.

I have no idea why it now completes booting. I was running a harddrive diagnostic (from Grub, not Ubuntu), I left my house at one point and had forgotten to plug in the charger so when I returned home the battery was drained. There was about four hours on the expected time to completion when I left and I was gone for about two hours, so it definitely didn't complete the diagnostic.

But for some reason the laptop's now working fine, it's been a week since then and I haven't encountered any further errors or problems.

Comment: What "startup application to run a setup script for an application" did you add? Since this seems to have caused the problem, it would seem appropriate to focus on this and give all the detail you can. Vague generalities are not useful in troubleshooting.

Comment: Status please...